# Response Interceptor Pattern with AngularJS and BreezeJS

Tags: angularjs, response, breeze, interceptor

On the matter of building a Request Interceptor, the BreezeJS documentation seems to be replete.  However, I've been struggling with the my attempts to build a Response Interceptor while using BreezeJs and AngularJs.  Does anyone have a good workable example?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Breeze can be configured to use angular's `$http` and `$q`, so interceptors you create in angular work for breeze requests:

http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/breeze-angular-service

https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.labs/blob/master/breeze.angular.js

Answer (score 0):

And you want to look at the JsonResultsAdapter which is used both by query and save to materialize response data from the server into entities on the client.